# default values for the maximum and minimum attributes of the long range validator in JSF

Tags: validation, jsf, default

```
<f:validateDoubleRange minimum="4" maximum="5"/>

<f:validateDoubleRange minimum="4" />

<f:validateDoubleRange maximum="5"/>
```

I want to know if only one attribute value above is like if minumum=4 then want is the default value for  maximum attribute or if  maximum is given then what is the default value for the minimum attribute .

what are the default values for the maximum and minimum attributes of the long range validator in JSF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default values are just the smallest and largest possible values. You can find them as `MIN_VALUE` and `MIN_VALUE` constants on the wrapper types `java.lang.Double` and  `java.lang.Long`.

- [`Double#MIN_VALUE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#MIN_VALUE)

  > A constant holding the smallest positive nonzero value of type double, 2<sup>-1074</sup>. It is equal to the hexadecimal floating-point literal `0x0.0000000000001P-1022` and also equal to `Double.longBitsToDouble(0x1L)`.
- [`Double#MAX_VALUE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#MAX_VALUE)

  > A constant holding the largest positive finite value of type double, (2-2<sup>-52</sup>)·2<sup>1023</sup>. It is equal to the hexadecimal floating-point literal `0x1.fffffffffffffP+1023` and also equal to `Double.longBitsToDouble(0x7fefffffffffffffL)`.
- [`Long#MIN_VALUE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#MIN_VALUE)

  > A constant holding the minimum value a long can have, -2<sup>63</sup>.
- [`Long#MAX_VALUE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#MAX_VALUE)

  > A constant holding the maximum value a long can have, 2<sup>63-1</sup>.

Comment: that means if we are not specifying the minimum or maximum values then it can validate any value usually we enter.